# Spring CrudRepository: Entities not attached with programmatic config, attached with DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I was testing some simple use cases using a CrudRepository and cannot explain the following:
When letting spring auto-configure my application (using @DataJpaTest on my test class + providing properties & schema via application.properties and schema.sql), all entities of my tests are correctly attached to the persistence context and any change is correctly reflected in the database.
However, when I'm providing a custom configuration, they seem to be detached and therefore changes are not reflected.

I came across this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289962/spring-boot-jpa-crudrepository-entities-are-not-attached-to-persistencecontext) that mentioned that the context would close after the call to CrudRepository method returns which would explain why are the entities detached but it is then contradictory with my first example.

Could someone explain me what is the difference between the auto config and my programmatic one which would cause this?

Model and repo:

```
@Entity(name = "contents")
@Table(name = "contents")
public class PersistableContent
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq", allocationSize=10)
  public Integer id;
  
  @Column
  public String value;
  
  public PersistableContent() { }
  public PersistableContent(String value) { this.value = value; }
  public Integer getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
  public String getValue() { return value; }
  public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}

@Repository
public interface PersistableContentRepository extends CrudRepository<PersistableContent, Integer> { }
```

First test and config (Entity is attached):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "jpa.repositories" })
@EntityScan("jpa.model")
public class MyTestConfiguration { }

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {MyTestConfiguration.class})
public class PersistableContentRepositoryTest
{ 
  @Autowired
  private PersistableContentRepository persistableContentRepository;

  @Test
  public void updateNewlySavedSupposedlyAttachedEntityTest()
  {    
    PersistableContent toUpdate = new PersistableContent("toUpdate");
    persistableContentRepository.save(toUpdate);
    
    toUpdate.setValue("updated");
    
    PersistableContent updated = persistableContentRepository.findById(toUpdate.getId()).get();
    
    assertThat(updated.getValue(), is(equalTo(toUpdate.getValue())));
  }
}
```

Second test and config (Entity is detached and assertion failing):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "jpa.repositories" })
public class MyTestConfiguration
{
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource()
  {
    DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    datasource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    datasource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:default;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
    datasource.setUsername("sa");
    datasource.setPassword("sa");

    // schema init
    Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("schema.sql");
    DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, datasource);

    return datasource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                     JpaVendorAdapter jpaVenderAdapter)
  {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("jpa.model");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVenderAdapter);
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVenderAdapter()
  {
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory)
  {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)
public class PersistableContentRepositoryTest
{ 
  // same test than above, the only difference is that:
  // I'm not using @DataJpaTest nor @ContextConfiguration
  // I'm importing my Configuration using @Import
}
```

EDIT:
To understand if it was related to the DataJpaTest auto-configuration, I decided to create another test class annotated with SpringBootTest and I created a new configuration annotated with SpringBootConfiguration. Rerun the same test and this time, the entities are no more attached when retrieved via the repository. I'm wondering if my whole problem is not related to what DataJpaTest does with the test class, something like making every single test as a transaction in order to clean up after each test. If this is the case, it was counter-intuitive for me as I used DataJpaTest in purpose to limit the auto-configuration to only JPA components while still expecting the repository to behave as it would do with a full auto-configuration or with a custom/programmatic one.